# Spring - How to access an object in a partial view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm creating a simple blog application using Spring Boot and Fremarker as the template engine. So basically I have Author and Post.
I have a navbar.tfl which is a partial view. So when I select the Authors dropdown in this partial view, I would like to list all author's names, and include a link to show all their posts.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">FSM IT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Posts <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/post/list">List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Authors <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <!-- GET ALL AUTHORS HERE. HOW? -->

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Guest User</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The problem is that the navbar is a partial view, so it's shared by all views. I know we could do something like model.addAttribute("authors", authorRepository.findAll()) in the controller to pass it to the view, but since navbar is a partial, I would have to do that in all my controllers.

In Ruby on Rails I would do something like this in my view:

```
<% Author.all.each do |author| %>
```

and then read all the authors names in my navbar partial view.

But with Spring, I have no idea how to do this.

Could you help me with that?

Here's my Author Repository (which extends CrudRepository, so I have a findAll method for authors):

```
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.domain.Author;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {

}
```

The Author domain:

```
package com.example.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Author {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;

  // Posts
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
  private List<Post> posts;

  private Author() {}

  public Author(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Author{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`@ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) annotation in your controller:

> `@ModelAttribute` methods are used to populate the model with commonly needed attributes for example to fill a drop-down with states or with pet types, or to retrieve a command object like Account in order to use it to represent the data on an HTML form.

```
@ModelAttribute("authors")
public Iterable<Author> getAuthors(){
    return authorRepository.findAll();
}
```

This adds the `authors` model attribute to your Spring MVC model. If you place this in your controller, you would have this attribute automatically available in your template.

If you need this model attribute on many controllers, have a look at the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation as described here:

> `@ModelAttribute` methods can also be defined in an `@ControllerAdvice`-annotated class and such methods apply to many controllers. [See the the section called “Advising controllers with `@ControllerAdvice` and `@RestControllerAdvice`”](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice) section for more details.

Comment: You rock. Thank you so much Johannes. Worked flawless!

Comment: You are welcome. You would do me a favour if you mark this answer officially as the accepted answer :-). Thank you